# How do I access context and args in resolver at the same time?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

This is an example of a resolver in my nestJS application (using graphQL):

In the first query I'm accessing the context, in the second one I'm accessing the args via decorator.

```
import { Args, Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql'

@Resolver('List')
export class ListResolvers {
  constructor(private readonly listService: ListService) {}

  @Query(() => [Data])
  async getList(obj, args, context) {
    const token = context.token
    return this.listService.getList(token)
  }

  @Query(() => [Data])
  async getList(
    @Args('param') param: GetListParam
  ): Promise<Array<Data>> {
    return this.listService.getList(param)
  }
}
```

But I do need to pass both: `param` and `token`:

```
return this.listService.searchList(param, token)
```

How do I access the context in the second query (the one using `@Args`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access request headers by using this method.
first add **context** in graphqlModule import in **app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
GraphQLModule.forRoot({ ..., context: ({req}) => ({req})})
]
```

then use context in graphql queries like this

```
 @Query(() => [Data])
  async getList(
    @Args('param') param: GetListParam,
    @Context('req') req
  ): Promise<Array<Data>> {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    return this.listService.getList(param)
  }
```

Comment: From where do I get `@Context` and `req`? I already set `context: ({ req }) => ({ token: req.headers.authorization })` in the app.modules.ts

Comment: @user3142695 What do you mean from where? just import Context from @nestjs/graphql, and use it in resolver like this `@Context('token')  token`. This should work